# SSRS first day of year of prior month

Tags: date, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that is supposed to show Calendar YTD sales *as of the last day of the prior month*. I'm having trouble calculating the start date parameter, dynamically.

If I run the report on 12/15/2017, the last day of the prior month is 11/30, so I'd like to see 1/1/2017-11/30/2017. If I run the report on 1/15/2018, the last day of the prior month is 12/31, so I'd like to see 1/1/2017-12/31/2017.

For the start date, I was using **Today.AddMonths(1-Today.month).AddDays(1-Today.day).AddYears(1-Today.year)**, which really just returns the first day of the current year based on the rundate of the report. This works fine in any month except January.

When I use that formula and run the report in January, it returns 1/1/2018 instead of 1/1/2017.

I realize that the reason it doesn't work is because I'm basing the calculation on "today" instead of the last day of the prior month, I just don't know the correct formula that will do what I need.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your start date use this...

```
=DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)
```

this just takes the curent date (2018-01-06 in this case), subtracts a month giving 2017-12-06, gets the year for this date (2017) then we just set the month and day both to 1 which finally gives us 2017-01-01

If we ran this on 20th June 2018 we would follow the same process, subtract a month giving 2018-05-20 get the year (2018) and then set the month and day to 1 giving us 2018-01-01

For the end date use

```
=DateAdd("d",-(Day(today)), Today)
```

Here we just subtract a number of days from todays date. The number of days we subtract is todays day number so for 2018-01-06 we subtract 6 days which gives us 2017-12-31
If we ran this on 20th June 2018 we would follow the same process, take 2018-06-20 and subtract 20 days which gives us 2018-05-31

Comment: Thank you, Alan! This is exactly what I needed, and I appreciate the help, and also the detailed explanation.